# Add extra field in Djanjo CMS 2.4 admin by language

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm adding an string-type extrafield to my CMS page model, if this extrafield is not empty will replace the default field title of the page 
with its content:

```
class MyPage(models.Model):
page = models.ForeignKey(Page, unique=True, verbose_name=_("Page"),
    editable=False, related_name='extended_fields')
extra_page_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

`extra_page_title`has the title (string) that will replace the cms default title page, which gets this title from `request.current_page.page_title`.

My problem is when I save the new title in the`extra_page_title` variable, it does work and replace the default title but it replaces the default title for all languages avaliable.

How can I use the CMS Page model to differentiate by language and save the title depending on the language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to have an extra title to replace the original menu title as I explained in the question above. The `TitleExtension` doc. didn't worked out for me because of the Django CMS version.

Looking in the [Django CMS 2.4.0 documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/getting_started/configuration.html) I found a setting linescript which enables this feature automatically.

```
CMS_MENU_TITLE_OVERWRITE = True
```

Adding this to the *settings.py* file adds an empty field in the Django admin where I can write any name to my menu/section for each language the site has, and it replaces the field name correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `TitleExtension`, see [the documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/how_to/extending_page_title.html).

Comment: I'm using django-cms v2.4.0- couldn't find any documentation of cms extensions for this version out there, any help? i've installed django-cms-extensions==0.1.0 but it didn't find module named extensions.

Comment: This was added in 3.0. I highly recommend you upgrade to the latest stable version.